# Packet Sniffing Outlook - > Exchange using MAPI

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, mapi, packet-sniffers

I am trying to implement packet sniffing for traffic from an Outlook client to an Exchange server. This communication uses MAPI over HTTPS (Outlook anywhere) as far as I can tell. I don't think I am using MAPI over RPC.

Traffic comes across as TLS which I can decode in wireshark as I have the appropriate certificate loaded. I cannot view the original content of the mail I sent during my test, it is still encoded.

How can I decode messages so I can read the original content in plain text?

I am creating temporary files for each stream that is handled and storing them unchunked and ssl-decoded. Example below. If I view said files in less they appear to be binary:

> PROCESSING
>
> DONE
>
> X-StartTime: Fri, 16 Dec 2016 23:17:12 GMT
>
> X-ElapsedTime: 5
>
> ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@^E^@<9B>^B^A^E<80><9F>^@^D^D^C^A^@^@^@^A^A^Ctestets)^@s^@Y^@^Q^@h^@^V^@p^@^@^A^@^Q^@^B^A^@^E^@^@^O^B^A
> *^C^@^@9^C^@^O^C^@^E9^*^@^X^@^X^@^@:^C^@q:^B^A^@^@^U^D^A=^C^@^X^A*^*^@8^@^X^@X^@^A`^*^@f^A^A^D^@^@>^D
> ^F^@^H^@^@^@^@/o=ExchangeLabs/ou~^@ Administra^@^@^@^@tive Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=^@^@ ^@Recipientsi^@cfb4ddc8c1ba4733a3d23^@^@^@^@4e1321845da-shayne.civi^@S^@h^@a^@y^@X^U^@n^@e^@ ^@C^@i^@v^X^@t<98>^@r<88>^@s^X^@^@(^@^*^A<80>.^@c^@^*^A^Q^@^@<9D>0^@^@w^@^@^@ܧ@B^P^Z^H^@+/<82>*^K^@^@O^Gh<9D> ^D^D<82>^A^@<80>^P^A^@@<87>^K        @^@w(^@^@^Zd^@g(^@)^Atx^@o^@k^@<89>^Ao^@m@^B?^B ^*^A^M
> ^M^A^@^P^@&^?_^ON<98>  h5^GZ]w<83>~^@^B^@^W^R^K5^Ko^C   ^F^M/8^@=^@E^@x<88>^@<89>^Bnz^ALH^@b8^A^@u^@i ^@A^@@
> ^Bm<88>^Cn^X^@s^Br^@tX^@v^@Gx^@^ApX^@(^@F^@Y^@D^@I^@B^@O^@bESC^EEHh^@2^@3X^GP<98>^@L^@T^@)(^Cc8^B=^@R^AI^Fp^X^@<99>^Et^B^@c^@f<88>^D4GU^CdX^@8^X^@1x^@a<88>^@7h^B3H^@3^@^B4^A18^@2(^@8h^@5^@a^@-X^B^E<8F>       ^A^@^@^P^@^@^G<93>
> ^W^@^Vs l<82>/<8A>MR]Oˌ^Sx^@^@^DUB^V^@^@^L^@^@^@^@^A^C^@^@^A^@^@^@^@

I have read through all documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499(v=exchg.80).aspx about these protocols I could find.

---

EDIT:

With the use of a program called fiddler and it's Office Inspectors, specifically MAPIInspector, I am able to view almost all the information I need.

[https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Inspectors-for-Fiddler](http://Fiddler%20Office%20Inspectors)

I am able to view in plain text: subject, recipient list, sender information, file attachment names, file attachment contents and much more, but I still cannot find the body of the message.

I believe the message is stored in:
ExecuteRequestBody->ROPBuffer->Payload->ROPList->ROPWriteStreamRequest->Data.

I believe the ROPWriteStreamRequest is what I need.

The content is encrypted and/or obfuscated. I was able to find the obfuscation algorithm for RPC which is XOR by 0xA5, but I am not sure if this is done before or after compression. I suspect the compression algorithm is LZ77.

Comment: Did you expect some plaintext infos? I think that will nor work due to internal encryption and compression.

Comment: If the information was already encrypted over https I don't see the need for further encryption, though I am not saying that is not the case, I don't know what the case is. If it is compression, then I would like to know what inflate algorithm I must use to get the plaintext.

Comment: how about content vs. transfer encryption? that's not the same ...

Comment: Well I am just sending an email with the subject test and the body test and trying to sniff that, so I am not encrypting the content myself. Are you suggesting outlook is doing the content encryption? If so then would it be possible at all for me to view the content?

Comment: I have updated my original comment with what progress I have made and where my problems still exist... any further insight would be awesome.

Comment: What you now see might be in the microsoft Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format (TNEF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExecuteRequestBody->ROPBuffer->Payload->ROPList->ROPWriteStreamRequest->Data saved the attachment content. The email content is stored in RopSetPropertiesRequest->PropertyValues->the 11th TaggedPropertyValue (whose property tag is PidTagBodyHtml). The content is html format.